# C# Adding to BindingList causes Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview, bindinglist, begininvoke

I'm working on a program that is adding to a couple of `BindingLists` in 2 separate threads.  The action of adding to these `BindingLists` adds rows to 2 separate `DatagridViews`. As I want both `DataGridViews` to update concurrently, both threads are started in the same button click method. If I start only one of the threads, a single `DataGridView` updates just fine with no errors. However, if I start both threads in the method, I get the following error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
```

This however does not happen in every run.  If I run the code 10 times this error might happen 4 or 5 out of the 10 times while the other 5 runs run perfectly fine.

This is a fairly big program so I will post the snippets that are directly involved.  An extra eye would greatly be appreciated in case you can see something I am not seeing.

Method which creates the `BindingLists`

```
private void GridForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

            spreadRows = new List<SpreadData>();
            positionRows = new List<PositionData>();
            spreadPositionRows = new List<PositionData>();   

            spreadBList = new BindingList<SpreadData>(spreadRows);
            positionBlist = new BindingList<PositionData>(positionRows);
            spreadPositionBlist = new BindingList<PositionData>(spreadPositionRows);


            this.spreadDataBindingSource.DataSource = spreadBList;
            this.dataGridView5.DataSource = this.spreadDataBindingSource;

            this.positionDataBindingSource.DataSource = positionBlist;
            this.dataGridView3.DataSource = this.positionDataBindingSource;

            this.positionDataBindingSource1.DataSource = spreadPositionBlist;
            this.dataGridView2.DataSource = this.positionDataBindingSource1;


            this.positionDataBindingSource1.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(positionDataBindingSource1_ListChanged);
            this.positionDataBindingSource.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(positionDataBindingSource_ListChanged);

            .......
        }
```

Method that creates the threads:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             ......

            Thread t = new Thread(retrievePositionData);
            t.Start();

            Thread f = new Thread(retrieveSpreadPositionData);
            f.Start();

        }
```

Method that adds to 1st `BindingList`:

```
private void retrievePositionData()
{
    PositionData theData2;

    while (true)
    {
        .........

        char[] delimeter2 = { '+' };

        string[] text2 = reply2.Split(delimeter2);                   

        theData2 = new PositionData();

        theData2.uniqueId = text2[1];
        theData2.Security = text2[2];

        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { positionBlist.Add(theData2); });

        ......

     }

}
```

Method that adds to the second `BindingList`:

```
 private void retrieveSpreadPositionData()
 {
     PositionData theData2;

     while (true)
     {
        ......

        char[] delimeter2 = { '+' };

        string[] text2 = reply2.Split(delimeter2);              

        theData2 = new PositionData();

        theData2.uniqueId = text2[1];
        theData2.Spread_Price = text2[3];

        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { spreadPositionBlist.Add(theData2); });

        .......

      }
}
```

The program stops at the `this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { positionBlist.Add(theData2); });` line of the `retrievePositionData()` method.  And this only happens when both threads are started.  If only one thread is started in the button click method, there are no problems.

Thanks in advance for your help.